# Creating an index on an XML type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery

I have a question about a situation I may find myself in.

A database is many GB's large but consists only of 1 column (an [XML type column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx)).

My question is about reporting on this type of column. Can I create an index based upon XML data (I assume not). Do I have any options or will I just have to accept that, due to the amount of data, using the XQuery may not be lightning fast?

Comment: define 'an XML type column' ? example ?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121(v=sql.90).aspx (assuming you are using SQL Server)?

Comment: That's fine. it's just a link only answer and you can mention it yourself, add your experience with using the indexes and close it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Vikdor's comments in the OP

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

*XML indexes can be created on xml data type columns. They index all tags, values and paths over the XML instances in the column and benefit query performance. Your application may benefit from an XML index in the following situations*